# Insert row in a Google Worksheet with Java

Tags: java, android, insert, spreadsheet, worksheet

How can I insert a row in a Spreadsheet?
I try with this code but have an error:

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Method Not Allowed`

at line: `row = service.insert(url, row);`

Why **Method Not Allowed** ???

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException
 {

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
    FeedURLFactory factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
    String key = "***my_key***";
    URL spreadSheetUrl = factory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(key,"public","full");
    WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(spreadSheetUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

     WorksheetEntry worksheet = feed.getEntries().get(13);
     URL url = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();


     ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
     row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("header", "aaa");

     row = service.insert(url, row);
 }
}
```

Help me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has been found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772453/error-in-uploading-post-via-blogger-api-v1). Perhaps you are not using the full correct formal for the URL, but I can understand why you wouldn't want to post that publicly. However, it's hard to tell if that it the problem or not without seeing it.

Comment: I think URL is correct becouse if I try to get information of these worksheet ,I get it!! @David Meredith